# QWebEngineView - Render after loading finished

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I am encountering an issue with rendering images on a QWebEngineView, where the HTML document loads immediately, causing flickering, while external objects load asynchronously. I was referring to the documentation for QWebEngineView (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineview.html#setHtml) and found that the setHtml function seems to load and render simultaneously, making it difficult for me to intercept the process in the middle.

Is my understanding correct, and if so, what could be a potential solution to prevent flickering and ensure that rendering only occurs after the page loading is complete? Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following code, but it didn't help.

```
class CustomWebEngineView : public QWebEngineView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomWebEngineView(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QWebEngineView(parent)
    {
        page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::ShowScrollBars, false);
        page()->loadFinished.connect(this, &CustomWebEngineView::onPageLoadFinished);
    }

public slots:
    void loadHtmlWithImages(const QString &html)
    {
        setHtml(html);
    }

private slots:
    void onPageLoadFinished(bool success)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            // HTML content has finished loading along with its resources
            page()->toHtml([this](const QString &html)
            {
                // The HTML content is available after loading
                // You can perform any additional processing here if needed
                setHtml(html);  // Set the HTML content to the view after resources are loaded
            });
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    CustomWebEngineView view;

    // Your HTML content with image sources
    QString htmlContent = R"(
        <html>
        <body>
        <img src="image1.jpg">
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        </body>
        </html>
    )";

    view.loadHtmlWithImages(htmlContent);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```